# Angular 6 httpclient error details

Tags: angular6, angular-http, angular-httpclient

I have an Angular 6 app and when I make an http request:

```
this.myService.login(this.form.email.value, this.form.password.value)
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(
         data => 
                {
                       //do something on success
                },
         error => 
                {
                     //here the response `error` if I use console.log(error)
                     //shows just Bad request if my API returns 404. 
                     //How can I access other properties of the error, like 
                     //the body?
                }
);
```

How can I access other properties of the error in case the HTTP call returns an error?

In case of an error the APi will return 404 Bad Request but there will be a also a JSON body:

```
{
    Status: "Error",
    Body : "Something happened"
}
```

How can I access this in my error handling?

Comment: In the http request use `this.http.get(url, { observe: 'response' });`. You will get the response status along with all the details.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way (**TESTED with angular 6**)

first call the api in other class i.e (api helper service)

```
MyApiCall(data:any) {
    return this.http.post('Your api url', data);
  }
```

in the above method do not add `.map` or `.subscribe` to the http post method

NOW, call this method from your component class from which you are going to interact with the API

```
formSubmit() {
     // your logic
      this.apiservice.MyApiCall(apivalues)
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            let httpresponse = data;
            let response = data.json();
            if (httpresponse.status == 200) {
               // logic when success
              }
              else {
               // else
              }
            }
          }, err => {
            let httpresponse = err;
            let response = err.json();
            if (httpresponse.status == 0) {
                //if api is dead or couldn't reach
            }
            else {
              //for other request , 401 404 etc
            }
          });
    }
  }
```

to get success codes ,

```
    let httpresponse = data;
```

^^ this will get the httpresponse to you (status, code, httpurl , other api info)

```
    let response = data.json();
```

^^ this will get you the data created and send by the api (the actual business response)

same is the logic with error

```
    let httpresponse = err;

    let response = err.json();
```

^^^ 1st line gets you base http response
^^^ 2nd line gives you error message created in api (user custom body)